# Type function from type T to type integral where sizeof(integral) >= sizeof(T)

Tags: c++, c++11

I want a type function, that takes a type T and returns the smallest integral type I satisfying `sizeof(I) >= sizeof(T)`.

Any thoughts, insights, or comments about how to approach this? C++11 is available, thoughts with C++14 are welcome.

For the curious:
I'm working through elements of programming.
I have a function which maps from a group, like int, to itself. Let x be in the domain of the function and y be obtained by applying f to x some number of times. I want to know how many times I have to apply my function to x before I get y. This value is called the distance, and is some integer. If the group type is specified in k bits, the total number of distinct values is `pow(2,k)`. The total number of possible jumps between elements is then `pow(2,k) - 1`. So an integral type with the same size as the group type is sufficiently large to hold all the possible distances that this distance function could return.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? `sizeof(I) > sizeof(T)`says nearly nothing about  how `I` should look like, do you simply want it to consist of a char array?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what would be a use of such a function?

Comment: I think this could be solveable with std::enable_if and typedefs, but your problem is how you want it to behave if sizeof(T) > 8; I with a char array is btw easy implementable.

Comment: @Paranaix *returns the smallest integral type `I`*. A `struct` containing a `char` array does not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @Praetorian yeah I havent seen that at the first glance, though a char array might still be solving his usecase (which we dont know), just wanting him to know that its far more easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct best_type {
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        sizeof(Head) >= sizeof(T), 
        identity<Head>,
        best_type<T, Tail...>
    >::type::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct type_to_integral {
    typedef typename best_type<T, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, uint_least64_t>::type type;
};
```

Live demo [here](http://ideone.com/nJubEG).

Comment: -1 Not enough `std::conditional` :-) Seriously though, it'd be nice to add yet another `std::conditional` in `type_to_integral` predicated on `is_signed<T>` that converts the type returned by `best_type::type` into the same signedness using `make_signed` and `make_unsigned`

Comment: I should have just tried to chug it out. That's a solid simple answer, thanks. Although isn't the third condition `(i <= 4)` a little two conservative? Can't an 8 words `double` be represented by `uint64_t`? Note: I changed the requirement from `>` to `>=`.

Comment: @Polymer you're right. My answer was aimed at the first version of your question.

Comment: Add one more conditional: `i<=sizeof(uint_least64_t)` -- that does nothing if it is no bigger, but if it is it adds support.  You could also take a sorted list of `int`eger types and find the smallest that is big enough...

Comment: @Yakk yep, the sorted list was a good one. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Even better! Does what I need. Thanks!

Comment: It does not fail gracefully: feed it `int64_t[2]`.  Add empty `best_type<T>`, specialize with inheritance to either `best_type<T, Tail...>` or `identity<Head>` and you cut boilerplate and make it SFINAE friendly.  Did not know that unused `typedef`s are also ignored as are functions: is that standard or gcc optimization? (oh, and awesome)

Comment: @Yakk okay, now it fails with a nice `static_assert` :D.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example I used based on mfontanini's answer and Yakk's comments.

```
//In metaprogramming library header
template<bool B, typename T, typename F>
using Conditional = typename std::conditional<B,T,F>::type;

//In application header
template<typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct big_enough{
  using type =
    Conditional<sizeof(T) <= sizeof(Head),
      Head,
      typename big_enough<T, Tail...>::type
    >;
};
template<typename T, typename Head>
struct big_enough<T, Head>{
  using type = Head;
};
template<typename T>
struct containing_integer{
  using type =
    typename big_enough<T, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, uint_least64_t, double>::type;
  static_assert(std::is_integral<type>::value, "Type is too large");
};
```

Notice I added a `double` at the end of the type list, and I squeezed `identity` into a specialization of `big_enough`. If I decide to include identity in a header, then I may change

```
template<typename T, typename Head>
struct big_enough<T, Head>{
  using type = Head;
};
```

to

```
template<typename T, typename Head>
struct big_enough<T, Head> :
  identity<Head>
{};
```

Because the later uses SFINAE.

Now trying to find an integral type bigger then 'int64_t[2]' returns the error:

```
Transformation.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct containing_integer<long long int [2]>':
Transformation.cpp:86:54:   required from here
Transformation.cpp:33:3: error: static assertion failed: Type is too large
   static_assert(std::is_integral<type>::value, "Type is too large");
```

Which is easy to read.